# Specify a separate location for settings.xml in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to specify a different location for settings.xml for the maven build other than the default one (`<USER_HOME>/.m2/settings.xml`).

I have tried the `-s` flag but it is not working. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found an easy way to do this..

Go to the 'Build' Section of the job and click "Advanced". There is a 'Settings File' option there. Specify the location your 'settings.xml' file.

Answer (score 7):

Actually -s flag works. We use it maven jobs.

Under *Build* section add **Invoke top level Maven targets** and set *Goals* to `[your goals] -s [path/to/settings.xml]` (e.g. `clean deploy -s /some/path/settings.xml`)

Comment: Build section doesn't have Invoke top level Maven targets. But, the pre-build steps section has it. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 6):

The jenkins [managed script plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin) allows you to manage multiple maven settings files. Once it is installed, you can add configurations in *Manage* > *Manage Files* > *Add new config* > *[Global] Maven Settings File* where you store the configuration.

In the job configurationn in the *Build Configuration Settings* check *Provide Configuration Files* and select the settings.xml in *Managed Files* > *File*.

Comment: Another useful plugin is the "configuratuon file plugin": https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

Comment: the managed script plugin extends the config file provider. so yeah, if you just look for maven settings file the mentioned plugin is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your JOB configuration

than to the Build section

Add build step :- Invoke top level maven target and fill Maven version and Goal

than click on Advance button and mention **settings** file path as mention in image
[image]